# Angular 8 mapping unknown amount of object keys into model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a model for the following object, specifically `GroupedMenu`. The categories listed in grouped menu are dynamic, in this case they are burritos and desserts, but in another call it could be pizza, drinks, tacos, enchiladas.

```
{
    "name": "Taco Taco",
    "address": "123 somewhereville",
    "groupedMenu": {
        "burritos": [
            {
                "name": "good burrito",
                "category": "burritos",
                "price": "1.59$",
                "description": "It's a burrito, ok?"
            }
        ],
        "desserts": [
            {
                "name": "cinnamonStick",
                "category": "desserts",
                "price": "$5.00",
                "description": "Cinnamon is healthy, try a spoonful."
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Here is how I've formed the model so far:

```
export interface Restaurant {
    name: string;
    address: string;
    groupedMenu: GroupedMenu;
}

interface GroupedMenu {
    [key: string]: MenuItem;
}

export interface MenuItem {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    img: string;
    price: string;
}
```

This seems to work for my use-case, but I'm not sure if it's the correct implementation.

How should I model `GroupedMenu` so that it handle a dynamic amount of object keys with unknown names (e.g. burritos, desserts, pasta, sides, somethingRandom). Or is my implementation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty standard for dynamic key names.